# How to access the children structure in solidity from a mapping in the Parent class?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a customer structure and within the structure i have a mapping to another structure called CartItem. I have a addToCart function where i want to add a new CartItem as a child structure in the Customer structure. This is my codes on the Solidity contract. I want to access the child structure from the children structure in my Javascript file. is it like this customer[i].cartItems? Because I cant seem to access the child struct

```
// CUSTOMER
struct Customer {
    uint256 id;
    address owner;
    string name;
    string addressLocation;
    string phone;
    mapping(uint256 => CartItem) cartItems;
    uint256 itemCount;
}

mapping(uint256 => Customer) customers;
uint256 public customersCount;
```

```
struct CartItem {
    uint256 id;
    uint256 productId;
}
```

```
function addToCart(uint256 _id) public {
    uint256 i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= customersCount; i++) {
        if (customers[i].owner == msg.sender) {
            customers[i].cartItems[customers[i].itemCount].push(
                CartItem(customers[i].itemCount, _id)
            );
            (customers[i].itemCount)++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push()` on storage arrays. But the `customers[i].cartItems[customers[i].itemCount]` is a mapping. So you can assign to it using this snippet:

```
// `customers[i].itemCount` is the mapping key
// `CartItem(customers[i].itemCount, _id)` is the value

customers[i].cartItems[customers[i].itemCount] = CartItem(customers[i].itemCount, _id);
```